Dereferencing box in iterator breaks when mutable
I've encountered an error I can't wrap my head around when building a wrapper type over a HashMap<TypeId, Box<dyn MyTrait>>:
The following functions works fine for iteration over all elements:
pub fn iter(&self) -> impl Iterator<Item = &dyn System> {
    self.inner.values().map(Box::as_ref)
}

However, when I try to write the same in a mutable way, I'm getting a lifetime error:
pub fn iter_mut(&mut self) -> impl Iterator<Item = &mut dyn System> {
    self.inner.values_mut().map(Box::as_mut)
}

Error: "lifetime may not live long enough
returning this value requires that '1 must outlive 'static"
I've tried specifying the lifetimes in the function declaration to make it work, with no success. I do not understand why the second version breaks ?
I know that I can change the return type to be an iterator over mutable boxes, but I would like to keep the API clean and not expose those.
Is there a reason that I'm missing on why what I'm doing is wrong ? How could one break it if it was allowed ? Is this a known issue ?
Edit
Example Code
Code that seemingly doing the same thing have different compilation result.
use std::collections::HashMap;

trait MyTrait {}

fn my_as_mut(b : &mut Box<dyn MyTrait>) -> &mut dyn MyTrait {
    b.as_mut()
}

struct Map {
    inner: HashMap<u32, Box<dyn MyTrait>>,
}

impl Map {
    pub fn iter(&self) -> impl Iterator<Item = &dyn MyTrait> {
        self.inner.values().map(Box::as_ref)
    }
    pub fn iter_mut(&mut self) -> impl Iterator<Item = &mut dyn MyTrait> {

        // Error
        self.inner.values_mut().map(|b| b.as_mut())
        
        // Error 
        self.inner.values_mut().map(Box::as_mut)
        
        // Works
        self.inner.values_mut().map(|b| { b.as_mut() })

        // Works
        self.inner.values_mut().map(|b| {
            let a = b.as_mut();
            a
        })

        // Works
        self.inner.values_mut().map(my_as_mut)
        
    }
}

Error
error: lifetime may not live long enough
  --> ***\src\main.rs:19:41
   |
17 |     pub fn iter_mut(&mut self) -> impl Iterator<Item = &mut dyn MyTrait> {
   |                     - let's call the lifetime of this reference `'1`
18 |         // Error
19 |         self.inner.values_mut().map(|b| b.as_mut())
   |                                         ^^^^^^^^^^ returning this value requires that `'1` must outlive `'static`
   |
help: to declare that `impl Iterator<Item = &mut dyn MyTrait>` captures data from argument `self`, you can add an explicit `'_` lifetime bound
   |
17 |     pub fn iter_mut(&mut self) -> impl Iterator<Item = &mut dyn MyTrait> + '_ {
   |                                                                          ++++
help: to declare that the trait object captures data from argument `self`, you can add an explicit `'_` lifetime bound
   |
17 |     pub fn iter_mut(&mut self) -> impl Iterator<Item = &mut dyn MyTrait + '_> {
   |                                                                         ++++
help: consider adding 'move' keyword before the nested closure
   |
19 |         self.inner.values_mut().map(move |b| b.as_mut())
   |                                     ++++


self.inner.values_mut().map(|b| {b.as_mut()}) works but self.inner.values_mut().map(|b| b.as_mut()) doesn't, idk why tho

@啊鹿Dizzyi I just checked it out, and you are right.
This is really weird, isn't this a compiler issue ?

Likely isn't a compiler issue, but to be sure, what is the definition of self?

As mentionned in the comments, the following worksk:
pub fn iter_mut(&mut self) -> impl Iterator<Item = &mut dyn System> {
    self.inner.values_mut().map(|b| { b.as_mut() })
}

This is really weird, and maybe just a compiler issue ?
Anyway, this can be closed.

better make it |b|{ let a = b.as_mut(); a} otherwise one cargo fmt will make it error  again

Actually, the current api is unnecessarily inflexible. The original type of the trait objects is dyn MyTrait + 'static. Therefore, it would be reasonable for the iterator to return &'_ mut (dyn MyTrait + 'static) instead of the current &'_ mut (dyn MyTrait + '_) (although I can't come up with any code that needs that change).
It is actually slightly surprising that any of the examples which return this type compile at all. The reason it is surprising is that, usally, &'short Type<'long> can not be transformed into &'short Type<'short>. But trait objects are an exception to this (see https://users.rust-lang.org/t/solved-variance-of-dyn-trait-a/39733). The reason only some of the examples compile is probably that this transformation can only happen in certain places.
Here is some example code.
use std::collections::HashMap;

trait MyTrait {}

struct Map {
    inner: HashMap<u32, Box<dyn MyTrait>>,
}

impl Map {
    pub fn iter(&self) -> impl Iterator<Item = &(dyn MyTrait + 'static)> {
        self.inner.values().map(Box::as_ref)
    }
    pub fn iter_mut(&mut self) -> impl Iterator<Item = &mut (dyn MyTrait + 'static)> {
        self.inner.values_mut().map(Box::as_mut)
    }
}

playground

The reason is that Box::as_mut() has a fixed signature of &mut Box<T> -> &mut T, and the T must stay the same.
